Close excel file with python with Net 8
I'm working with autodesk programs (Robot structural Analysis[RSA], Dynamo).
For the past i used RSA 2022 with Dynamo 2.11.0.
At the moment we are upgrading to RSA 2025 which is using Dynamo 3.0.4.
In the image below a simple preview of our workflow.
enter image description here
So every single excel file should be closed by the script.
Which worked pretty good in RSA2022 with the following script:
import sys
import clr
import System 

clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c')
from Microsoft.Office.Interop import Excel
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal

def excel_close(lst_namefile):
    xlApp = Excel.Application(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"))
    print(xlApp)
    allWorkbooks = Excel.Workbooks(xlApp.get_Workbooks())
    print([x for x in allWorkbooks])
    lst_WkbsName = [Excel.Workbook(x).get_Name() for x in allWorkbooks]
    for namefile in lst_namefile:
        if namefile in lst_WkbsName:
            Tesluiten = Excel.Workbook(allWorkbooks.get_Item(namefile))
            Tesluiten.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

toList = lambda x : x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]
OUT = excel_close(toList(IN[0]))

Now with the upgrade to RSA2025 i still need to use this script, but i get the following error.

Message
FileNotFoundException : Unable to find assembly ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c’. at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr) [’ File "

I already did some research and questioning, SEE other forum
But it seems related to the Net 8.
My question is: is there an other way to close the excel file with a python script?

I think this answer would work for you

Your code is incomplete, I get a compiler error on toList(IN[0] - variable undefined. When I specify the Excel file to be closed and it is currently open it works fine. As in OUT = excel_close("xl_data.xlsx")
